# Not getting screen Height and widht in Android

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I using both Using Activity or without Activity, Not getting both height and width in Android.Please correct me, What i am doing wrong.

**Here With Activity:**

```
public class LandPort extends Activity{

    public final static int height = 0;
    public final static int width = 0;
    Context context;
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();


    public LandPort(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getHeight() {

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        return width;
    }

}
```

In MainActivity:

```
LandPort lp= new LandPort(getApplicationContext());
        int height = lp.getHeight();
        int width =lp.getWidth();
```

Getting ***height and width both 0;***

**Another Without Activity:**

```
public class GetHeigthWidth {

    public final static int height = 0;
    public final static int widht = 0;
    Context context;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    public GetHeigthWidth(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getHeight() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int height = display.getHeight();
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int widht = display.getWidth();
        return widht;
    }

}
```

From MainActivty:

```
GetHeigthWidth ghw= new GetHeigthWidth(getApplicationContext());
        int height = ghw.getHeight();
        int width =ghw.getWidth();
```

Aslo get ***Height and Width 0.***

So, How to get Actual Height and width in this>

Comment: you have not set the content (layout) to your activity. i guess that's the reason you get 0

Comment: where is Your onCreate() and setContentView(R.layout.yourView) inside Your activity?

Answer (score 0):

call your getHeight(); getWidth() stuff in

```
    int height;
    int width;
    ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(globalListner);

    OnGlobalLayoutListener globalListner = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
              height = view.getHeight();             
              widht = view.getWidth();
        }
    });
```

and dont forget to remove that global listner at the End :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);      

    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
}
```

you need to initialize your activity.

UPDATE

You need to do this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class GetHeigthWidth {

    public final static int height = 0;
    public final static int widht = 0;
    Context context;
    WindowManager wm;
    Display display;

    public GetHeigthWidth(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        wm = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    }

    public int getHeight() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int height = display.getHeight();
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int widht = display.getWidth();
        return widht;
    }

}
```

Comment: I did this, it is right but i want to create another class and get height and width.

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```